# Is it possible to change the IP address and Device Name in Windows CE via CMD or Batch?

Tags: batch-file, ip, windows-ce, static-ip-address

Ideally, I'd have a batch file on my desktop that I could click to quickly change these configurations, but the batch scripting tutorials I've been looking at don't seem to work for Windows CE. Anyone know how to do this?

I want to set a static IP, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway, and Device Name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy and fast way (as double clicking a bat) to change your network configuration, typically you'll need to write a tool.

The tool must:

1. change values in the registry for your network adapter; the registry entries are something like:
   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\NETADAPTER\Parms\TcpIp]
   "IpAddress"="192.168.0.100"
   "DefaultGateway"="192.168.0.1"
   "Subnetmask"="255.255.255.0"`
2. ask the adapter to renew his address (you can use NDISConfig.exe to do this)

If you have an hive based registry (data in registry are stored permanently and will be there after a reboot) you can reboot the device to easily implement the second step.

Hope this is helpful